# How is the conversion in the python struct module done?

Tags: python, c, struct

I need to unpack information in python from a C Structure,
doing it by the following code:

```
struct.unpack_from('>I', file.read(4))[0]
```

and afterwards, writing changed values back:

```
new_value = struct.pack('>I', 008200)
file.write(new_value)
```

a few examples:
008200 returns an syntaxerror: invalid token.
000010 is written into: 8
000017 is written into: 15
000017 returns a syntaxerror.

I have no idea what kind of conversion that is.
Any kind of help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is invalid python code and is not related to the struct module. In python, numbers starting with a zero are octal (base 8). So, python tries to decode 008200 in octal but '8' isn't valid. Assuming you wanted decimal, use 8200. If you wanted hex, use 0x8200.